# Exporting boxfuse image

Tags: virtualbox, cloudcaptain

I have created a working image which I can start by simply calling `boxfuse run <image name>`. Can I export the image to a file and hand it over to my colleagues so they can run it from virtualbox?

Answer (score 2):

Simply share you Boxfuse user and secret. You can then push your image to the Boxfuse Vault from one machine and pull it down on the other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't like to share secrets. Well, shared secret is not a secret any more. I'll ask different way: does the generated image is located somewhere on my machine? Can I just take it and use elsewhere?

Comment: Fair point. These are just the credentials to ensure you both have access to the same images and AWS account. You can find the images on disk under ~/.boxfuse , but note that this is strictly private and undocumented and subject to change at any time.